# express js - how to set static file for multiple sub-folder?

Tags: express, static-files

How to set static file for multiple sub-folder ?
In app.js i set :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

and my public structure :

```
- public
   - admin
      - images
      - css
      - js
   - site
      - images
      - css
      - js
```

I can not get a image in admin/images with:

```
img(src="logo.png")
```

Comment: try img(src="admin/images/logo.png")

Comment: Actually, i try img(src="../admin/images/logo.png") and it's right, but if it load in another page (differrent url), it will wrong.

Comment: it depends if you use the url from the server or client side. on server, try img(src="./public/admin/images/logo.png") that way the path is relative to root on server. in the client ./public/* is root

Comment: I did : img(src=baseUrl+"admin/images/logo.png") with baseUrl is global variable for baseUrl = 'http://' + host + ':' + port;

Comment: For me to be able to provide any assistance, I need to see how you use the line in question. Do you render the page on the server or is it part of a SPA?

Answer (score 0):

You should set absolute path, for exsample, you shared **public** folder then if you want to get image on you web site try

> admin/images/logo.png

for get all path to the image

> ${hostname}:${port}/admin/images/logo.png

Answer (score 0):

You miss `./`, when using `__dirname` use use basepath at that code write

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));
```

then you can call you file `{host}:{port}/admin/page/...`